# How to Setup a New Google Analytics Classic Property

Tags: google-analytics

Now that Universal is out of beta, I cannot find out how to setup a new property with Classic Analytics. Is this still possible? I don't see an option for it when creating new properties. Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 2):

No, Google Analytics removed the option to create Classic properties. It's only Universal now.

Answer (score 0):

All Properties that you create today are Universal Analytics activated.

The new tracking code is recommended. But you can still use the old tracking code to send data to them.

Relevant Docs:

- Classic Tracking Code: [ga.js](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/)
- Universal Tracking Code: [analytics.js](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/)